# Почему не выводится последний сout?

Tags: c++, xcode

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
string word;
    while ( cin >> word )
        cout << "Прочитано слово: " << word << "\n";
cout << "Все слова прочитаны! \n";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://ideone.com/B6HQgJ — что тут не так?

Comment: `while ( cin >> word )` - когда это условие должно не сработать?

Comment: это программа из книги "Язык программирования С++. Вводный курс" я просто скопировал программу чтобы разобраться в ней, я не знаю когда это условие должно не сработать

Comment: Программа считывает каждое слово из предложения и выводит это слово, когда она вывела все слова она пишет Все слова прочитаны!, но у меня этот cout не работает

Comment: Закройте поток ввода (Ctrl-Z в Windows, Ctrl-D в Linux).

Comment: Зачем и что это значит? Как это сделать на маке?